# How to use Map() to create HTML table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I receive a JSON object back from my DB

```
0: {id: 8364, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0, content: "2015 "}
1: {id: 835, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 1, content: "2016"}
2: {id: 836, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 2, content:"2018"}
3: {id: 837, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 3, content:"2017"}
4: {id: 838, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 4, content:"Change"}
5: {id: 839, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 5, content:"Profit"}
6: {id: 830, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 1, columnIndex: 0, content: "Cash Summary"}
7: {id: 831, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 1, columnIndex: 1, content: "$1200"}
```

I want to create a HTML table using the data returned.
The data is saved in 
`const sortedData`
How can I use the map function to use the rowIndex and columnIndex to render a table into a react component

In this case the table is 6X6, how do I dynamically set the  elements in the even a different size table is returned

Currently I have

```
    let table = sortedData.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <table>
          <tr key={i} value={item}>
            <td>{item.content}</td>
            <td>{item.content}</td>
            <td>{item.content}</td>
            <td>{item.content}</td>
            <td>{item.content}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      );
    });
```

Comment: Can you please show your effort what you've tried so far?

Comment: Do you can  to show tr and td based on row index and column index?

Answer (score 1):

You want to create an array of arrays `[[rowIndex1Item1, rowIndex2Item2], [rowIndex2Item1]]`, categorized by `rowIndex`. Each inner-array will be a table-row and their items will be table-cells.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-bush-wpn4m

Try something like below:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  { id: 834, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0, content: "2015" },
  { id: 835, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 1, content: "2016" },
  { id: 836, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 2, content: "2018" },
  { id: 837, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 3, content: "2017" },
  { id: 838, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 4, content: "Change" },
  { id: 839, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 5, content: "Profit" },
  {
    id: 830,
    tableId: 137,
    rowIndex: 1,
    columnIndex: 0,
    content: "Cash Summary"
  },
  { id: 831, tableId: 137, rowIndex: 1, columnIndex: 1, content: "$1200" }
];

const createTable = () => {
  const organizedByRows = data.reduce((obj, curr) => {
    if (!obj[curr.rowIndex]) {
      obj[curr.rowIndex] = [];
    }

    obj[curr.rowIndex].push(curr);
    return obj;
  }, {});

  const tableContent = Object.values(organizedByRows).map(row => {
    return (
      <tr>
        {row.map(item => (
          <td>{item.content}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    );
  });

  return <table>{tableContent}</table>;
};

const App = () => {
  return <div>{createTable()}</div>;
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: It wont work for different table id , you need to create seperate table when tableId changes

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is mostly correct except that you have to move the `<table>` element out of map like below.

```
<table>
    {sortedData.map((item, i) => {
        return <tr key={i} value={item}>
            <td>{item.content}</td>
            <td>{item.content}</td>
            <td>{item.content}</td>
            <td>{item.content}</td>
            <td>{item.content}</td>
        </tr>;
        })
    }
</table>;
```